# Show the content of a Word file in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, textbox

I have a Textbox with muiltilne option enabled.
I want to show the content of a specific word file into that textbox. how can I do this? I use this code but it's just showing the name of the file.

```
private void btnOpen_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Word File";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Word Files (*doc)|*docx";   

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

        object fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        // Define an object to pass to the API for missing parameters
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,ref missing, ref missing);

        String read = string.Empty;
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            string temp = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
            if (temp != string.Empty)
            data.Add(temp);
        }
        doc.Close();
        word.Quit();   
        txtTxt.Text = data.ToString();

    } 
}
```

This is a windows form app in C#.

Please help!

Comment: it will do because you said `txtTxt.Text = file` where you previously set file to be the filename.. at no point have you read the contents of the file - you opened it, but that seemed to be it.

Comment: @BugFinder How can I read the content. can you please Edit my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the data to the textbox using the line

```
txtTxt.Text = data.ToString();
```

`data` is a string list. Assigning it like this won't work unless you've overloaded the .ToString() method.

Iterate through the list and add it to the textbox. Something like this

```
foreach(var item in data)
{
    txtTxt.Text += item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution.
Just need to add a loop at the end. thanks to "Mohamed Najiullah".

```
private void btnOpen_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Word File";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Word Files (*doc)|*docx";   

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

        object fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        // Define an object to pass to the API for missing parameters
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,ref missing, ref missing);

        String read = string.Empty;
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            string temp = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
            if (temp != string.Empty)
            data.Add(temp);
        }
        doc.Close();
        word.Quit();   
       foreach(var item in data)
{
    txtTxt.Text += item;
}

    } 
}
```